# Latest Compatible Asp.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

What the latest ASP.Net Identity version I can use in a non-Core .Net?

I'm trying implement role-based claims, and I see that code snippet:

```
roleManager.AddClaimAsync(...
```

I did some research, and I discovered "add Claims directly for Roles" is a new feature for ASP.Net Identity Core...

For now, I'm using ASP.Net Identity 2.x (for .Net 4.6). I have some option? The Identity Core needs of .Net Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest non-Core Identity is 2.2.1, source code for this found on [Codeplex](http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/).

If you need to add claims to roles you'll have to implement that yourself - that's not hard: you need to add a table that holds claims, but references Role instead of user - see existing UserClaims table.

Then when users login you'll have to read all users roles and all claims for them and add them in `GenerateUserIdentityAsync`, like in this [sample](https://github.com/trailmax/ClaimsAuthorisation/blob/master/ClaimsAuth/Infrastructure/Identity/UserManager.cs#L75).

Bear in mind that claims are getting overwritten in `SecurityStampValidator` ([sample](https://github.com/trailmax/ClaimsAuthorisation/blob/master/ClaimsAuth/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L98)), so you do need to add claims to the cookie in that method, otherwise you'll loose the extra claims when identity is regenerated.

Comment: Formidable, Max! Thank you. The hard part was understand about SecurityStampValidator, but I read your references and implemented myself.

Comment: @ClickOk Good stuff! glad this helped you